# Conditionally customize WooCommerce cart grand total output based on a fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

I try to do a quite simple thing but for me i don´t get it to work.

This is from the wc-cart-functions.php

```
        if ( ! empty( $tax_string_array ) ) {
            $taxable_address = WC()->customer->get_taxable_address();
            $estimated_text  = WC()->customer->is_customer_outside_base() && ! WC()->customer->has_calculated_shipping()
                ? sprintf( ' ' . __( 'estimated for %s', 'woocommerce' ), WC()->countries->estimated_for_prefix( $taxable_address[0] ) . WC()->countries->countries[ $taxable_address[0] ] )
                : '';
            $value .= '<small class="includes_tax">' . sprintf( __( '(includes %s)', 'woocommerce' ), implode( ', ', $tax_string_array ) . $estimated_text ) . '</small>';
        }
    }

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', $value );
}
```

The $value should be different if any **`$fee`** is applied.
But I only get **`0.00 €`** Value from **`$fee`** Variable if I check for.

Could someone please help me with simply apply the Value of the FEE in a Variable and check in a simple **`if`** clause like:

> if fee is applied ---> 1 
>   else ---> 2

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see you can use the **`woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html`** filter hook located in that `wc-cart-functions.php` core code, to alter the output of grand cart total:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'custom_cart_totals_order_total_html', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_totals_order_total_html( $value ) {
    // Get the fee cart amount
    $fees_total = WC()->cart->fee_total;

    // HERE is the condition
    if( ! empty($fees_total) && $fees_total != 0 ){
        // Change/customize HERE $value (just for test)
        $value .= " <small>($fees_total)<small>";
    }

    // Always return $value
    return $value;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

> Never overide core files, as this is something prohibited, dangerous and not convenient for many reasons

**You will need to customize the code in the condition for `$value`**

Comment: Wohoooo! Awsome thank you!!! Works perfekt for my needs. Just two small problemes left and you saved my life. I need to pass the same to the overview after checkout and to the e-mail that is sent to the customer. Any idea on how to do the trick? ------> 10000000 Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes it did! Thanx a lot. But what about the e-mail and after checkout? Would you please be so kind helping me there as well??